# Use of urllib2 in Google App Engine throws "Deadline exceeded while waiting for HTTP response from URL:..."

Tags: python, google-app-engine, urllib2, urlfetch

I am using urllib2 for Google App Engine (GAE) in python.
Very often the app crashes because of the following error:

> Deadline exceeded while waiting for HTTP response from URL: ....

The Source looks like this:

```
import webapp2
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def functionRunning2To5Seconds_1()    
    #Check if the Url could be parsed
    try:
        url         ="http://...someUrl..."
        req         = urllib2.Request(url,headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
        page        = urllib2.urlopen(req)
        htmlSource  = BeautifulSoup(page)
    except Exception  e:
        logging.info("Error : {er}".format(er=str(e)))

    #do some calculation with the data of htmlSource, which takes 2 To 5 Seconds

#and the handler looks like:
class xyHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self, uurl=None):
        r_data1 = functionRunning2To5Seconds_1()
        r_data2 = functionRunning2To5Seconds_2()
        r_data3 = functionRunning2To5Seconds_3()
        ...
        #show the results in a web page
```

I found this [doc](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/?hl=de) which states :

> You can use the Python standard libraries urllib, urllib2 or httplib
>   to make HTTP requests. When running in App Engine, these libraries
>   perform HTTP requests using App Engine's URL fetch service

and this:

> You can set a deadline for a request, the most amount of time the
>   service will wait for a response. By default, the deadline for a fetch
>   is 5 seconds. The maximum deadline is 60 seconds for HTTP requests and
>   60 seconds for task queue and cron job requests.

So HOW do I do this? How to set a timeout on urllib2?

Or, do i have to rewrite the whole application to use the App Engine's URL fetch service?

(PS: Does anybody know a secure way to run the "r_data1 = functionRunning2To5Seconds_...()" calls in parallel?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html

```
urllib2.urlopen(url[, data][, timeout])
```

> The optional timeout parameter specifies a timeout in seconds for
>   blocking operations like the connection attempt (if not specified, the
>   global default timeout setting will be used).

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by Paul, you can pass the timeout parameter. On App Engine it is tied to the URL fetch and will adjust its deadline to a maximum of 60 seconds. Keep in mind that if the urlopen takes more than the time specified in the timeout parameter, you'll get DeadlineExceededError coming from google.appengine.api.urlfetch_errors.DeadlineExceededError instead of the usual socket.timeout. It's a good practice to catch this error and retry / log if necessary. See [1] for more information on dealing with DeadlineExceededError.

[1] - https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/deadlineexceedederrors

Comment: Where do you got the 10 seconds limit from? All i can find is 60 seconds. Is this something gae specific, or was ist just a typo?

Comment: A typo, sorry. The limit is 60 seconds / 10 minutes (Task Queues).